# Windows not collecting logs. Error: The WinRM service is not listening for WS-Management requests

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-event-log, eventviewer, winrm

**I am getting this error**

```
The WinRM service is not listening for WS-Management requests. 

 User Action 
 If you did not intentionally stop the service, use the following command to see the WinRM configuration: 

 winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
```

**but my WinRM quickconfig is running:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

**In the EventViewer Subscription, this error is showing and but not connecting taking logs from remote machines.**

> [GANGA.DOM.DOMAIN.COM] - Error - Last retry time: 12/10/2019
> 3:13:08 PM. Code (0x80338126): WinRM cannot complete the operation.
> Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is
> accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
> WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
> default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
> access to remote computers within the same local subnet.   Next retry
> time: 12/10/2019 3:23:08 PM.